# Postgresql. Значение столбца из всех таблиц где есть этот столбец

Tags: sql, postgresql

DB Postgresql
Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу получить выборку вида (table_name, table_name.age) 
Мне нужно получить значение столбца age из всех таблиц где есть этот столбец(age)

На данный момент есть вот такая функция

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION union_all_tables()
 RETURNS TABLE
      (
        age   bigint
      ) AS
$$
DECLARE
 dynamic_query text = '';
 r_row         record;
BEGIN
 FOR r_row IN SELECT table_schema || '.' || table_name qualified_table_name
           FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
           WHERE column_name = 'age' 
LOOP
  dynamic_query := dynamic_query || format('UNION SELECT ' ||                                      
                                           'age ' ||
                                           'FROM %s ',r_row.qualified_table_name) || E'\n'; -- adding new line for pretty print, it    is not necessary
   END LOOP;

 dynamic_query := SUBSTRING(dynamic_query, 7) || ';';

 RAISE NOTICE 'Union all tables in staging, executing statement: %',    dynamic_query;
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE dynamic_query;
 END;
$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: добавить table_name в возвращаемый тип данных и в формируемый запрос

Comment: добавить 
RETURNS TABLE(
tbl_name text,
age bigint)
, а так же 
LOOP
dynamic_query := dynamic_query || format('UNION SELECT ' ||                                      
                                       'age, ' || '''%s''' ||     
                                       ' FROM %s ',r_row.qualified_table_name, r_row.qualified_table_name) || E'\n'; -- adding new line for pretty print, it    is not necessary
END LOOP;
При выполение функции обязательно нужно указывать нужные столбцы
with val as (
  select age, tbl_name from union_all_tables() as qwert)
  select * from val